# Open Source High School Textbooks

Tags: secondary-education, textbooks

**Where can I go to find open source high school level textbooks?** I'm especially interested in geometry and algebra, though probability and trig are also useful.

I'm interested in rearranging and adapting these to my school's integrated math curriculum to fit the South African national curriculum.

This question is basically the same as [Open-Source Math Textbooks](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/open-source-math-textbooks), except I'm looking specifically for high school - not undergraduate - textbooks.

One example of what I'm looking for is [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Subject:K-12_mathematics) but unfortunately most of these books are unfinished.

Comment: I maintain a catalog of free textbooks at http://theassayer.org .

Answer (score 8):

There is a website called [OpenStax](https://openstax.org/) that has pdf versions of textbooks (for various high school level classes including math) that you can download for free; you can also pay like $45 each to get hardback print copies. There are teacher resources as well that you can get access to after creating an account & verifying that you are really an instructor.

Comment: https://openstax.org/

Comment: See also [this answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/8331/511) specifically on OpenStax calculus.

Answer (score 7):

Off the top of my head, these are the only two examples that I can think of:

- [Mathematics Vision Project](http://www.mathematicsvisionproject.org). It is an integrated curriculum aligned with the new common core standards.
- [EngageNY](http://www.engageny.org/mathematics) has also modules for high school.

Both are released under Creative Common [by-nc-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/) license.

On a side note, (at least in the US) most curricula need to be approved by the state boards of education before they are adopted by school districts, so there aren't many open source projects started because teachers wouldn't be able to use them in their classes.  For example, in California there is a law that require schools to provide students with the most recent instructional materials (Williams vs State of California). That is oftentimes translated in students having access to a semi-modern textbook at school and at home. Using materials that a teacher found on the internet could be interpreted as being out of compliance with the court order, no matter the quality of the materials.

Comment: The OP mentioned Africa. I think "Common Core" is Greek to the OP.

Answer (score 6):

[CK-12](http://www.ck12.org/teacher/) is a great source of material. Math for every high school topic, with options to edit material to suit your needs.

Comment: I will agree that it is a great source of material, but I am not sure the material is all that great, if you take my meaning.  My experience with CK-12 has had a large dose of "you get what you pay for".

Answer (score 6):

Siyavula develops excellent free online mathematics and science textbooks. These are designed to fit with the South African curriculum, grades 10 to 12 (but may be of use to those outside of South Africa).

PDF versions can be downloaded in English or Afrikaanse from their site: http://everythingmaths.co.za/

Answer (score 2):

If you have such a specific curriculum in mind, with presumably many interested parties, your best bet would be to try to band together a group of like-minded people and start writing away. Just look around for what makes open source projects successful, consider the language to use (I'd suggest LaTeX with the AMS packages, and a few ground rules) and where to host the project (some of the public git hosting sites, or perhaps http://sourceforge.net). Open source works by *you* scratching your own itch.

Answer (score 2):

Of the Common Core sources, the [Georgia materials](https://ccgpsmathematics9-10.wikispaces.com/) are my favorite. https://ccgpsmathematics9-10.wikispaces.com/ They are also at [the state website](https://www.georgiastandards.org/Common-Core/Pages/Math-9-12.aspx), but the superintendent just came out against the CCSS so who knows what will happen to them.

Geoff Krall, a teacher for New Tech Network schools has put together [a PBL map](http://emergentmath.com/my-problem-based-curriculum-maps/) I find extraordinarily useful.

Answer (score 2):

The [Orange Grove](https://www.floridashines.org/orange-grove) is Florida's "Open Educational Resource Repository".  It has resources both for K-12 and higher education.

Answer (score 0):

If you read Portuguese, here is the [Projeto Livro Aberto de Matemática](https://umlivroaberto.org/).