# Are there free, offline mathematics assesment and learning programs for grades 1 to 12?

Tags: software

So far I have found an offline version of Khan Academy, but that´s about it. Does anyone know of similar offline programs that one can use to teach mathematics? How about mathematics assesment? I have not been able to find any yet.

I´m looking for exclusively offline programs that can be used in remote areas where there is no internet available.

Answer (score 1):

You may use any [OER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_educational_resources) content. See the recommendations of the following questions:

- [Open Education Resources](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8137/open-education-resources)
- [Open-Source Math Textbooks](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/open-source-math-textbooks%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B)
- [How can I choose a free calculus textbook?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/how-can-i-choose-a-free-calculus-textbook)

Normally you can download an offline version of the OER-textbooks / OER-contents. If not, you can do it by yourself:

- With [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) you can download Youtube videos and playlists (also from other sites as Vimeo)
- With [wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) or similar programs you can make an offline mirror of a website, see http://fosswire.com/post/2008/04/create-a-mirror-of-a-website-with-wget/

Because of the free license of OER websites, you can download and redistribute their content. Mostly [Creative Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons) licenses are used. Have a look at the project's license page to see, what is under which circumstances allowed...